# Will I earn anything on win8 migration by upgrading to win 7 ultimate from home premium?

Tags: windows-7

I bought a lenovo x230 tablet, but to get handwriting recognition in my native language I have to upgrade to the win 7 ultimate version. Will I get a better version of windows 8 if I do this?

I can already get win 8 pro for cheap via win upgrade offer, but I don't think that has my language either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two versions of Windows 8.  The normal "Home" edition and Professional edition.  You can read about the differences between them on the `Building Windows 8 Blog` entry that explains the two versions.

```
I can already get win 8 pro for cheap via win upgrade offer, but I don't think that has my language either.
```

What makes you think that?  This offer is going to be offered in dozens of countries and over a hundred different languages.

You gain nothing by upgrading to Windows 7 Ultimate when Windows 8 Professional will have the same language support Windows 7 Ultimate has currently.

Comment: As long as one can install extra languages, display languages, via windows update in win8 pro. I'm all set.